# Branches filter not working in github actions

Tags: github, continuous-integration, github-actions

I'm creating a Github actions that is triggered on pull_requests and only when the branch name had a prefix  `feat/` or `fix/`.  Searching in Github docs, I found option that allow us to [filter of branches names](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#onpull_requestpull_request_targetbranchesbranches-ignore). So I implement it my action. E.g:

```yaml
name: <action name>
on:
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - 'feat/**'
      - 'fix/**'
```

But testing in my repo, the action isn't triggered more. So anyone had this same issue?

Comment: 1. Did you push this workflow on the default branch? Or is it only available on another branch? 2. How do you open the PR? Is it through another workflow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Searching more in Github Docs, I found a paragraph talking about branches filter, wherein this filter check the base branch name instead of head branch name. So, to trigger a action on pull_requests that the branch had a specific prefix, we need use the `startsWith` statement. [Reference](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/events-that-trigger-workflows#running-your-pull_request-workflow-based-on-the-head-or-base-branch-of-a-pull-request)

```yaml
name: <action name>
on:
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - 'feat/**'
      - 'fix/**'

# ignore all other available branch prefixes
    if:  ${{ !startsWith(github.head_ref, 'test/') && !startsWith(github.head_ref, 'docs/') && !startsWith(github.head_ref, 'style/') }}
    steps:
       runs-on: ubuntu-latest
#     ...
```

Comment: You could improve this answer by adding some yaml that demonstrates the use of the startsWith statement.

Comment: @Joman68 good idea bro. I edited the answer with a example.